# jquery animate on hover with multiple list-items

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

OK, I've got my desired animation to be very close to what I want; however I'm running into a bug.  http://garibaldi.juggernautwebdesign.com/ and it's the #menu-left nav (colourful one).  If you hover, it expands open like it's supposed to.  And if you let it **fully animate**, then hover over a new element OR hover off that list-item, it then closes, properly and a new item will open (if you hover over a new list-item).  However, if you hover over a list-item and then quickly hover off before it has time to fully animate, then it slides back down too far.  **Is there any way to stop any animations from happening, until the initial hover is fully animated?  I tried using the queue option, but that just stopped any animation on a hover out.**

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    //Left nav  
    $('#menu-left').children().addClass('closed');

    $('#menu-left > li a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.closed').live('hover', function() { 

        var position_open = parseInt($(this).css('bottom')) + parseInt($('.sub-menu', this).css('height')) - 12;
        $(this).animate({ bottom: position_open }, function() {
             $(this).removeClass('closed'); 
             $(this).addClass('opened');        
        });     
    }); 

    $('.opened').live('hover', function() {
        var position_close = parseInt($(this).css('bottom')) - parseInt($('.sub-menu', this).css('height')) + 12;
        $(this).animate({ bottom: position_close }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('opened');
            $(this).addClass('closed');
        });     
    }); 

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a flag before calling animate. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var animating = false;
        //Left nav  
        $('#menu-left').children().addClass('closed');

        $('#menu-left > li a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $('.closed').live('hover', function() { 

            var position_open = parseInt($(this).css('bottom')) + parseInt($('.sub-menu', this).css('height')) - 12;
                    if(!animating) { 
                        animating = true;
                $(this).animate({ bottom: position_open }, function() {
                 $(this).removeClass('closed'); 
                 $(this).addClass('opened');
                               animating = false;
                });     
                    }
        });         

    });
```

Also, try removing one of the hover handler code. Seems they are stepping over each other.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without more testing, but I'm betting your events aren't bubbling the way you'd expect. You're adding/removing the class while you're still hovering/animating, so the process fires a few times.

I would suggest rewriting the function to trigger off of mouseenter/mouseleave events, I think this would help you making sure the events only fire once. You may not even have to add/remove classes with this method..

```
$(".slide_box").live('mouseenter', function () {
    //animate up
})

$(".slide_box").live('mouseleave', function () {
    //animate down
})
```